# returning record List in remote procedure calls

Tags: rpc, record, smartgwt, gwt-rpc

i'm using

> smartGWT mobile

as the front end ,

> from the client UI i'm making an rpc call in return as an result i
>   need record List.

If i use record List it throws an compilation error saying record List package not imported or found. i need it in the form of record List. as example i have to search files based on its name , so the result should contain file name, its date and size .please help 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To my sense `Records` are Client side object, your rpc should return `Serializable` objects and into the Async `callback` you set the differents attributes of your records with the values coresponding found in the objects coming from the server.
For example in your rpc:

```
MySerializableType[] thesNodes = new MySerializableType[size];
........
return theNodes;
```

and somewhere else:

```
public class MySerializableType implements IsSerializable {
```